# Misclassification of variables in R

Tags: r, cross-validation

How can you create a function in R that will identify the misclassification of explanatory variables? For example using:

```
library("MASS") 
library("dplyr")
data(birthwt)
```

Which of the explanatory variables (x) (age, mother's weight, race, etc) performs best at
predicting response variable (y), low birth weight. I have tried:

```
 n.folds <- 10
    folds <- cut(sample(seq_len(nrow(birthwt))),  breaks=n.folds, labels=FALSE)

 for (i in seq_len(n.folds)) {
  train <- filter(x, folds != i)
  test <- filter(x, folds == i) 
  }

 my.model<- glm(y ~.,family = binomial, data =  train)
 tab=predict(my.model)
```

I think the following code may be used to find the misclassification?

```
1-sum(diag(tab))/sum(tab)
```

Comment: Do you mean you wish to compare R's classification to an existing classification? In that case you could just do e.g. `which(folds != my.data$classif)`

Comment: Oh no sorry the code above is just for the cross-validation. I think I am having the most trouble with trying to work out the misclassification rate of the response variables in relation to the explanatory variables in a logistic regression 

"glm(y~x, family = binomial, data =  train)"

Comment: Ok... just to check, are you aware you can use the `predict` function with your saved glm object?

Comment: I know that you have to create a train and test set which I have also edited into my question above and I know about the predict() function but not exactly sure how it fits into it all

Comment: Use e.g. `my.model <- glm(y~x, ...)`, then you can use `predict(my.model)`. Then you'll have at least the building blocks for your function.